# Compiz + MATE windows jump to previous workspace

Tags: compiz, workspaces, mate-desktop

I have a fresh Mint 13 Maya (MATE edition) with Compiz enabled. I also have a two-monitor set-up with the nVidia drivers with TwinView. I have set up 4 horizontal workspaces via CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Here is the behavior I try to eliminate: I open a window, say, browser, and put it to workspace number 2. When I switch to workspace 3 or 4, then back to workspace 2, the window is gone. It has jumped to workspace 1 somehow.

This annoys a lot. Could anyone help?

Here are some details:

- If you stay on workspace 2 windows never jump
- If you switch to workspace 1 and back to worspace 2 - windows do not jump. They seem to jump only if you switch to the right
- I have 2 monitors, and this behavior occurs only with windows displayed on the left monitor

Comment: What desktop environment/window manager? I've seen a feature in some WMs which allows you to grow and remove workspaces at will, maybe this is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Happens for me too - very annoying. I used to have 5 workspaces in a row under Ubuntu 10.04.
However, I did find that putting 4 workspaces in 2 rows stops the windows from jumping around. It's harder to click on a workspace but that's my fix for now.

Answer (score 1):

you should use CCSM (`sudo apt-get install ccsm`) to set "Desktop size" in the "General options" section

Set horizontal to, say, 4, vertical to 1, and (this is counterintuitive) number of desktops to 1